# Microsoft Office Outlook 2013 - Define a delegate from my contacts

Tags: delegates, outlook, contacts, gal

By default, in Microsoft Office Outlook 2013 I can define a delegate from the GAL (Global Address List). Is there a way to choose an entity from my contacts like can be done when sending an email?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interested in the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items. It allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. For example:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount()  
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts  
 If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then  
   Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
   Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
   oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account"  
   oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
   oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
   oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
   oMail.Send  
 End If  
Next  
End Sub
```